# To search for a string from the line in text file from the end of file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need to search for string "included into the field : 790" from the file abc.txt, where the string needs to be searched from the end of file using batch script.

abc.txt :

```
---Text file has contents------------------------------
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 897 Adding name
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 887 Adding field
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 887 Adding layout
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 807 Adding customization
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector included into the field : 790
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 906 Adding name
02/03/2021 Included into the area sector 876 Adding main header
```

I tried the below code snippet :

```
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ " %%a in (`findstr /i /c:"included into the field : 790" C:\abc.txt`) do (
set j=%%a
)
echo %j%>"C:\output.txt"
>nul findstr /c:"included into the field" "C:\output.txt" 
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
 echo found
) else (
 echo not found
)
```

However the code snippet doesnt check for the string and also there are multple occurences of string and I need the string which encounters first from the end of file. Any advise would be appreciated

Comment: "the first from the end" == "the last from the start". Your code does exactly that: get the last occurrence to the variable. Your code works fine for me as it is. Maybe there is an encoding problem with `abc.txt`?

Comment: Try `@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Type "C:\abc.txt" ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe" /I "included into the field : 790"') Do @Set "j=%%G"` instead.

Comment: @Compo, will check